# Sticky header animating when appearing but not when disappearing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, sass, styled-components

edit: here is my sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-morning-3f09m?file=/src/App.tsx

So, I have a sticky header made on React/Gatsby which should appear once the screen is scrollY >= 420. Once it hits 420px, it shows a nice animation sliding the header down. When I scroll the screen back up, however, the sticky header just "disappears" in a very cold way. The idea is that it would also "slide" up and disappear in a reverse way as it appeared. An example of what I want to achieve -> https://www.pretto.fr/
I want exactly this, for the header to slide when it comes down but when I scroll back up, for it scroll up disappearing.

The difference is that in this website the sticky header and the "main" header are two different components it seems. On my website, they are just one, and I'm just using props for it to go from `position: relative;` to `position: sticky;`

My header:

```
function Header(props: HeaderProps): React.ReactElement {
  const [sticky, setSticky] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('scroll', trackScroll)

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('scroll', trackScroll)
    }
  }, [])

  const trackScroll = () => {
    if (typeof window == 'undefined') {
      return
    } else {
      setSticky(window.scrollY >= 420)
    }
  }

  return (
    <Container id="container" sticky={sticky} className={`${sticky ? 'sticky' : ''}`}>
    ...
```

And my styled-components styles...

```
const smoothScroll = keyframes`
  0% { transform: translateY(-100%); }
  100% { transform: translateY(0px); }
`

const Container = styled.div<{ sticky?: boolean }>`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0 6rem;
  width: 100%;
  position: ${props => (props.sticky ? 'sticky' : 'relative')};
  top: 0px;
  height: 97px;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 3;
  background: ${props => (props.sticky ? 'white' : 'inherit')};

  &.sticky {
    animation: ${smoothScroll} 500ms;
  }
`
```

So the nice "sliding down" animation works once I scroll down to 420px. But as soon as I scroll back up it just disappears instead of "sliding up". Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: add a demo with the bug you describe please

Comment: @ssBarBee here https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-morning-3f09m?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 0):

The animation will fire only when 'sticky' class is added to the element, not removed. One of the possible solutions is to track scrolling up event and add another class with 'sliding up' animation that contains reversed styles - [general concept](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-tharp-erpei?file=/src/App.tsx)